# Import Products Dataflow Profile - 500 server error in console

Tags: magento-1.9, import, dataflow

I've successfully exported my products.  I made a few changes to the file (new sku, new product name), saved the file with a new filename and want to import the csv file.  This is what it shows my on screen.

```
 Starting profile execution, please wait...
 Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data
 Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Io :: load
 Loaded successfully: "/myfolder/myfile.csv".
 Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Csv :: parse
 Found 1 rows.
 Starting catalog/convert_adapter_product :: parse
Processed 0% 0/1 records
```

When I view my Javascript console, I see -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()   /index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/batchRun/key/12f765063f452bb84d1a1e57e84db089/
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Same issue with M 1.8.1 too.

Answer (score -1):

> Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Yes: https://woocommerce.com/

Not even kidding.